# Affine-space $A_{n}$ as group-action object vs as projective space subspace

Tags: group-actions, projective-space, affine-geometry

Are the affine-space $A_{n}$ as a group-action object vs affine-space $A_{n}$ as subspace (open set complement of a projective hyperplane: coordinate projective hyperplane, etc.) of a projective space $P_{n+1}$ (quotient space) rationale approaches mutually compatible?

Another way of stating the problem perhaps would be: is the approach of an affine-subspace as given by means of a faithful and transitive group action $A \times V \rightarrow{A}$ supportive of (or at least not incompatible with) the projective-space subspace approach (removing an hyperplane from $P_{n+1}$)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question. If $V^{n+1}$ is a vector space, $\mathbb{P}V$ is the corresponding projective space, and $\ell \in V^*\backslash\{0\}$, then you get an affine space $$A = \ell^{-1}(1) = \mathbb{P} V \backslash \ell^{-1}(0).$$ $\ell^{-1}(0)$ is also known as the hyperplane at infinity. The group of affine transformations is the subgroup of linear transformations of $V$ that preserve the affine hyperplane $\ell^{-1}(1)$. This is naturally isomorphic to the subgroup of projective transformations of $\mathbb{P}V$ that preserve the hyperplane at infinity.

Comment: Thank you! Theres an interesting issue linked to.the choice of different.types.of.hyperplanes to.get the hyperplane at infinity. Greetings